# Can a C# Class Library pull Browser information?

Tags: c#, browser, dll

I am attempting to create a DLL or class library that will pull information from the browser a client is using. So basically a client app will have a reference to this DLL and when the client is using the application, the DLL will need to capture their browser information. Is this possible using a class library? The web references don't resolve which makes sense because it's not a web type project.

Comment: A user can have several browsers installed. He can use them at the same time. Some of them might be "portable" (not installed, just copied, or maybe even run from a USB drive). So which one do you choose? :)

Comment: Good point haha, is there a way to tell which one is currently set as "focused"

Comment: Your question sounds like an X - Y problem.

Comment: What you are trying to do would only lead you to frustration. Don't do it, really.

Comment: I agree. I suggest you take a step back and tell us WHY you want to do this in the first place (what PROBLEM are you trying to solve)?

Comment: (And then there are also things like Maxthon or Lunascape which function like browsers, yet only host other browsers inside them, so it gets kinda weird trying to figure out just **what** a browser really is)

Comment: Yea after further discussion, we agreed to push this responsibility to the client instead. This request has been rejected so no i am good to go. :) Thanks everyone